# How to output objects with conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following:

```
if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0 || doSelect('State').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
  var dateText = doSelect("Date").siblings('td').text().split(/\s+/g);
  console.log(dateText);
  $wikiDOM.find('.nourlexpansion').remove();
  $wikiDOM.find("#coordinates").parent().remove();
  $('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" + doSelect("Location").siblings('td').text() + '<br>' + 
    dateText[0] + "&nbsp; " + dateText[1].replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp; " + dateText[2].replace(/;/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp;" + dateText[3].replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp; " + dateText[4] + "&nbsp; " + dateText[5] + "&nbsp; " +  '</li>');
}
```

This line defines possible results:

```
var dateText = doSelect("Date").siblings('td').text().split(/\s+/g);
```

The console could give:

```
["19", "May", "1945", "–", "22", "August", "1945"]
```

So to print these dates I do:

```
dateText[0] + "&nbsp; " + dateText[1].replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp; " + dateText[2].replace(/;/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp;" + dateText[3].replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ') + "&nbsp; " + dateText[4] + "&nbsp; " + dateText[5] + "&nbsp;
```

Which gives:

19  May  1945 –  22  August

but sometimes I don't have all these dates so `dateText[3]` might not exists just as much as it may exists `dateText[9]`

Not simply that, I use `.replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ')` or `.replace(/,/g , '&nbsp; ')` because sometimes the dates come out to be all stack together like `19,May,1945` and I also need to remove the `dash` or `comma` or `semicolumn`

Basically I am trying to do it in a way that it is consistent and doesn't gives error in console if certain `[N]` or `.replace` isn't needed and are not present.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

> 19 May 1945
>
> 22 August 1945

Sometime I even go the month and the date opposite like `August, 22, 1945`.

Am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: `moment(date).format("DDMMMMYYYY") --> 22 August 1945` ;) Check out [momentJS](https://momentjs.com)

Comment: will moment recognise `19 May 1945 – 22 August`? or `19,May,1945 – 22 August` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try something like this?

```
var dateText = ["19", "May", "1945", "–", "22", "August", "1945"];

var d = '';

for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
    d += dateText[i] + ' ';
}

console.log(d);
```

Console output: `19 May 1945 – 22 August 1945`

To get rid of the '-' and/or insert a line break you could easily modify the loop to handle that.  This keeps your code clean/simple and allows for easy changes which will impact all objects of this type in the future.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2s7nwju/1/

Comment: going to test it but it does look very promising and exactly what I needed